# Dynamically add to value of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamically-generated

http://jsbin.com/IKik/1/edit

So I'm trying to dynamically generate/append html tags into a textarea. As soon as the value is changed I can no longer dynamically generate html to the element. I can still type (obviously) but the generation process is invalid. Even though I got no errors.

I made a sample to show the problem I'm getting.
Any help/advise on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div id="contain" align="center">
  <button id="add1">Add 1</button>
  <button id="add2">Add 2</button>
  <button id="add3">Add 3</button>
  <button id="add4">Add 4</button>

  <textarea id="textbox">Default text</textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#textbox {
  width: 100%;
  min-height:30em;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  resize: none;}

#contain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#add1').click(Add1);
$('#add2').click(Add2);
$('#add3').click(Add3);
$('#add4').click(Add4);

var textbox = $("#textbox");

// Dynamic Add
function Add1() {
  textbox.val("Add 1");}

function Add2() {
  textbox.append("&lt;div class='gendiv'&gt;gendiv&lt;/div&gt;");}

function Add3() {
  textbox.html("<a href='http://bing.com/'>Bing</a>");}

function Add4() {
  textbox.text("&lt;img src='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4111/5208943327_ec7203ac0e.jpg'&gt;");}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.append()`, `.html()` and `.text()` methods do not work with form elements, for setting/getting value of a from element `.val()` method should be used instead:

```
function add2() {
  textbox.val(function(_, oldVal) {
       return oldVal + "string to be appended";
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured val should be used, but couldn't figure out how to get this to work so ended up messing around trying various ways and no luck.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
function Add1() {
  textbox.text("Add 1");}
```

instead of .val("Add 1")

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4HCr/

Comment: Negative the text inside a textarea is the .val. Your fiddle does exactly what I didn't want which is replacing the value with the dynamically generated one, instead of adding it to the value.